# What is wrong with my MySQL create a table code?

Tags: mysql, web, phpmyadmin

Why do I get this error from this code

```
CREATE TABLE `a9311211_AppBook`.`Requests` 
(
   `Name` VARCHAR( 15 ) UNSIGNED CHARACTER SET hp8 COLLATE hp8_bin NOT NULL ,
   `Category` BLOB UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
   `Dificulty` FLOAT( 2 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
   `Discription` LONGTEXT UNSIGNED CHARACTER SET hp8 COLLATE hp8_bin NOT NULL 
) ENGINE = MYISAM CHARACTER SET hp8 COLLATE hp8_bin
```

> MySQL said:
>    #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNSIGNED CHARACTER SET hp8 COLLATE hp8_bin NOT NULL, `Category` BLOB UNSIGNED NO' at line 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the `unsigned`

```
 CREATE TABLE `a9311211_AppBook`.`Requests` (
    `Name` VARCHAR( 15 ) CHARACTER SET hp8 COLLATE hp8_bin NOT NULL ,
    `Catagory` BLOB NOT NULL ,
    `Dificulty` FLOAT( 2 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
    `Discription` LONGTEXT CHARACTER SET hp8 COLLATE hp8_bin NOT NULL 
) ENGINE = MYISAM CHARACTER SET hp8 COLLATE hp8_bin
```

only numeric types can be `unsigned`

Answer (score 0):

it should be:

```
`Catagory` BLOB NOT NULL
```

`BLOB`cannot be positive nor Negative (*because it is not numeric*).